# No module named "datasets" even after installation

Tags: python, package, conda, environment, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to use the `datasets` package of `huggingface` . I am using conda and Git bash terminal in VS Code. The script file include

```
import datasets
```

However I got the message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'
```

It seems that the package has not been installed. However, `conda list` gives:
`datasets 2.14.1 py_0`

What should I do in this case please?

I have also try

```
python -c "import datasets; print(datasets.__version__)"
```

and obtained no error.